# Pygame installation error

Tags: python, pygame

I have installed Python 3.4.0 on a Win Vista Home Premiun 32bit machine with "Service Pack 2" installed.

Python installed to `C:\Python34`

I then chose the pygame windows binary `pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.2` since this is the closest to Python 3.4.0.

When in the shell or via a .py file and I use `from pygame import *`, I get the following error:

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Stuart/Desktop/Python Project files/g.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pygame import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.*
```

Comment: Install python 3.3 and download Pygame from Bitbucket at https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads.

Comment: that seems to work fine Martin, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a pygame install for python 3.4 at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/